# /dev/sdb* not available after boot - initramfs does not load uas and usb_storage modules

Tags: debian, boot, usb, initramfs

Initramfs on my Debian testing system is not able automatically load necessary kernel modules for external USB 3 HDD (Seagate Backup Plus 1T) if it was already plugged in when initramfs started. If I boot into initramfs shell, plug cable out and plug it back in, then device will show up and I will be able to mount it.

I don't need this device in initramfs, but `/dev/` filesystem created by initramfs is passed to main OS, where I do need it. I have to plug cable out and in to make device usable.

**How do I setup initramfs to settle this device?** Or how do I tell main OS to walk through hardware buses and handle all devices that udev in initramfs missed?

### Additional information

After I plug device off and on, two new modules are loaded:

```
# lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  1 uas
```

These modules are available in initramfs image:

```
# lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0-1-amd64 |grep -E '(uas|usb-storage)'
lib/modules/4.6.0-1-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.ko
lib/modules/4.6.0-1-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/uas.ko
```

`uname`, `dmesg` and `lsusb` output after plugging device in:

```
# uname -a
Linux pingwin 4.6.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1 (2016-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
# dmesg
[   53.412599] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   53.429652] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab24
[   53.429659] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[   53.429662] usb 2-2: Product: BUP Slim BK
[   53.429664] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[   53.429667] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: NA7K016V
[   53.455444] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   53.458787] scsi host6: uas
[   53.458962] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   53.459440] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  BUP Slim BK      0302 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   53.497569] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[   53.497586] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[   54.503950] ...ready
[   56.518071] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[   56.518077] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 2048-byte physical blocks
[   56.687950] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   56.687960] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[   56.688242] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   56.699372]  sdb: sdb1
[   56.700399] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk

# lsusb -v -d 0bc2:ab24

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ab24 Seagate RSS LLC 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x0bc2 Seagate RSS LLC
  idProduct          0xab24 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           2 Seagate
  iProduct                3 BUP Slim BK
  iSerial                 1 NA7K016V
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          121
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower               36mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     98 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
        MaxStreams             32
        Data-in pipe (0x03)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
        MaxStreams             32
        Data-out pipe (0x04)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
        MaxStreams             32
        Status pipe (0x02)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               0
        Command pipe (0x01)
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           22
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat        2047 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x000c
  (Bus Powered)
  U1 Enabled
  U2 Enabled
```

`udevadm` output on initramfs and working system (they are pretty much the same, the only differences are in `stat`, `iodone_cnt`, `ioerr_cnt`, `iorequest_cnt` and `urbnum`):

```
# udevadm info -a -p /sys/block/sdb on initramfs


Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdb':
    KERNEL=="sdb"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{badblocks}==""
    ATTR{capability}=="50"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{events}==""
    ATTR{events_async}==""
    ATTR{events_poll_msecs}=="-1"
    ATTR{ext_range}=="256"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
    ATTR{range}=="16"
    ATTR{removable}=="0"
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{size}=="1953525167"
    ATTR{stat}=="      72        0     4254      232        0        0        0        0        0      136      232"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0':
    KERNELS=="6:0:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS=="sd"
    ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
    ATTRS{device_busy}=="0"
    ATTRS{dh_state}=="detached"
    ATTRS{eh_timeout}=="10"
    ATTRS{evt_capacity_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_inquiry_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_lun_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_mode_parameter_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_soft_threshold_reached}=="0"
    ATTRS{inquiry}==""
    ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"
    ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0x7a"
    ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x8"
    ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0x7a"
    ATTRS{model}=="BUP Slim BK     "
    ATTRS{queue_depth}=="30"
    ATTRS{queue_type}=="simple"
    ATTRS{rev}=="0302"
    ATTRS{scsi_level}=="7"
    ATTRS{state}=="running"
    ATTRS{timeout}=="30"
    ATTRS{type}=="0"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="Seagate "
    ATTRS{vpd_pg80}==""
    ATTRS{vpd_pg83}==""
    ATTRS{wwid}=="naa.5000000000000001"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/host6/target6:0:0':
    KERNELS=="target6:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/host6':
    KERNELS=="host6"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="4-2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="uas"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="08"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="62"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="06"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="04"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2':
    KERNELS=="4-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="9"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="144mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="ab24"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bc2"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Seagate"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="BUP Slim BK"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{serial}=="NA7K016V"
    ATTRS{speed}=="5000"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="371"
    ATTRS{version}==" 3.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4':
    KERNELS=="usb4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="03"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="9"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0406"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0003"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.6.0-1-amd64 xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="5000"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="47"
    ATTRS{version}==" 3.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1e31"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="29"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="0f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x1949"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x103c"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

```
# udevadm info -a -p /sys/block/sdb on booted system

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdb':
    KERNEL=="sdb"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{badblocks}==""
    ATTR{capability}=="50"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{events}==""
    ATTR{events_async}==""
    ATTR{events_poll_msecs}=="-1"
    ATTR{ext_range}=="256"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
    ATTR{range}=="16"
    ATTR{removable}=="0"
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{size}=="1953525167"
    ATTR{stat}=="      72        0     4254      328        0        0        0        0        0      272      328"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0':
    KERNELS=="6:0:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS=="sd"
    ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
    ATTRS{device_busy}=="0"
    ATTRS{dh_state}=="detached"
    ATTRS{eh_timeout}=="10"
    ATTRS{evt_capacity_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_inquiry_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_lun_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_mode_parameter_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_soft_threshold_reached}=="0"
    ATTRS{inquiry}==""
    ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"
    ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0xd1"
    ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x48"
    ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0xd1"
    ATTRS{model}=="BUP Slim BK     "
    ATTRS{queue_depth}=="30"
    ATTRS{queue_type}=="simple"
    ATTRS{rev}=="0302"
    ATTRS{scsi_level}=="7"
    ATTRS{state}=="running"
    ATTRS{timeout}=="30"
    ATTRS{type}=="0"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="Seagate "
    ATTRS{vpd_pg80}==""
    ATTRS{vpd_pg83}==""
    ATTRS{wwid}=="naa.5000000000000001"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/host6/target6:0:0':
    KERNELS=="target6:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/host6':
    KERNELS=="host6"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="4-2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="uas"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="08"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="62"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="06"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="04"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2':
    KERNELS=="4-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="9"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="144mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="ab24"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bc2"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Seagate"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="BUP Slim BK"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{serial}=="NA7K016V"
    ATTRS{speed}=="5000"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="592"
    ATTRS{version}==" 3.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4':
    KERNELS=="usb4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="03"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="9"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0406"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0003"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.6.0-1-amd64 xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="5000"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="47"
    ATTRS{version}==" 3.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1e31"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="29"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="0f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x1949"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x103c"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

```
# /etc/udev/udev.conf (the same on booted system and in initramfs)
# see udev.conf(5) for details
#
# udevd is started in the initramfs, so when this file is modified the
# initramfs should be rebuilt.

#udev_log="info"
```

It doesn't matter if I plug disk into USB 3 or USB 2 port on computer.

USB2 devices plugged in before initramfs initialization are correctly recognized and settled. I don't have any other USB 3 device to verify if it would be affected as well. However, I could try with this disk on my friend's computer (with Ubuntu 16.04) - it was settled and available in `/dev/` after boot.

It doesn't matter if I generate initramfs by initramfs-tools or by dracut.

How can I ensure that `/dev/sdb*` related to this HDD is available in fully-booted system even if cable was plugged in before boot?

Comment: Do you have `/etc/udev/udev.conf` inside initramfs?  (to allow for udev rules in there).  And what is the output of `udev info -a -p /sys/block/sdb` within and outside of initramfs (when the device is there that is).

Comment: @grochmal Yes, `/etc/udev/udev.conf` exists in initramfs, but it's as good as none. Added to question. I have also added `udevadm info` output from initramfs (after plug out and in) and booted system, although they are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is a wild guess and a workaround (rather than a proper understanding of the issue) but it should work.

Make a `udev` rules file, say, `/etc/udev/rules.d/z30-seagate-disk.rules` and add the following rule:

```
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Seagate", ATTRS{product}=="BUP Slim BK", SYMLINK+="seagate"
```

This should force `udev` to make a second pass and add the disk as `/dev/seagate` block device.  You will also need to add that file to the `FILES` variable in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` so it gets into the `initramfs`.  (And run `mkinitcpio -p linux` to rebuild the `initramfs`)

Disclaimer: Tested on Arch, not on Debian, and not using USB 3.0.

---

Another workaround would be to force `uas` (USB SCSI) to be always loaded by the kernel.  Add to a file say `/etc/modules-load.d/seagate-disk.conf` the module name:

```
uas
usb_storage
usbcore
scsi_mod
usb_common
```

In theory only `uas` is needed, but I cannot replicate you issue therefore I'd try brute forcing everything that is needed to manage a USB HDD.  Again, add that file to `FILES` in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`.

This will force the kernel to have `uas` always loaded.  Maybe while `udev` is running though the buses it falsely assumes the the USB hubs/buses are not loaded with anything since the kernel has no USB modules loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. Neither `/dev/seagate` nor `/dev/sdb*` was available in initramfs or booted system. I could find `z30-seagate-disk.rules` file in `/lib/udev/rules.d/` in initramfs shell, so it was configured properly.

Comment: @MirosławZalewski - hmm... I bet on some small inconsistency between `uas` and `udev`.  I added another possible hack into the answer to get around it, not tested through.

Comment: Thanks for a tip. However, it did not help. I managed to force-load module and it shows as loaded when I do `lsmod` in initramfs. But disk still does not show in `/dev/`...

Comment: @MirosławZalewski - I figured out I do have a machine running kernel 4.6 (Arch not Debian though) and I do have a Seagate HDD too.  I tried to replicate your problem on that setup but without success, my disk appears in `/dev` if I connect it to the machine before booting it.  The only big difference on my machine is that all `usb` and `scsi` modules are loaded when the machine boots.  As a last resort I'd try brute forcing **all** modules that are needed to operate a USB HDD to be loaded at boot.  It is worth a try.

Comment: As closing comment: right now this issue is mostly settled, that is external HDD is recognized about 9 out of 10 boots. It seems that reboots have higher chance of leaving disk in unrecognized state. I am hesitant to say that this is hardware problem (for reasons that I can't elaborate in comment), but I think that I have exhausted all software means of solving this. My drive did not work in the past and it seems to work now. I am going to accept your answer as it was most helpful; however I don't consider this issue truly solved yet.

Comment: @MirosławZalewski - If that helps your spirits I, personally, consider Seagate a pretty poor hardware producer.  Had more than one disk controller on their disks die on me (and I do not use massive amounts of disks).

Answer (score 3):

Edit `/etc/modules` and add a line containing `uas`.

Then run `update-initramfs` (e.g. `update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)` to update the initramfs for the currently running kernel.  or `-k all` for all installed kernels).

Modules listed in `/etc/modules` are loaded automatically regardless of whether `udev` or anything else detects that they are needed.

This is also useful if you need or want to force a specific order for modules to be loaded, so that module `foo` will always be loaded before module `bar` (unless, of course, an earlier loaded module depends on `bar`).

As with any modules loaded by `modprobe`, you can set load time options in a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`.

e.g. I have `spl` and `zfs` listed in `/etc/modules`, and `/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf` contains:

```
# use minimum 4GB and maxmum of 8GB RAM for ZFS ARC
options zfs zfs_arc_min=4294967296 zfs_arc_max=8589934592
```

If you want to know what load-time options a module knows, use `modinfo [module] | grep parm`.  Module `uas` has none.